# This Question is about flutterflow and importing flutterflow packages

Tags: flutter

How to import flutterflow package in flutter code?

I expected to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you talking about this plugin? https://pub.dev/packages/flutterflow

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

Follow this documents https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/custom-widgets

I hope the problem will solve.